# javascript - check if cookie value is in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies

Im learning javascript right now, so this might be a really newb question! I googled it, but didnt found what I was looking for, maybe I just didnt googled the right thing, but yeah...Oh im not using any plug-ins for cookies.

I have a cookie named "country", the value is the user's country code, like US, CA, UK, AU or FR...
I want to display a block of content only if the country is, let's say DE, ES, AT, IT or NL.

The logic of what im looking for: if cookie "country" exist and country == one of the country in my array...

Im thinking about something like... But that is obviously too simple and not working :)

```
var countryArray = new Array["DE", "ES", "AT", "IT", "NL"];

if( $.cookie('country') && $.cookie('country') == countryArray ) { alert("working"); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for new browsers:

```
countryArray.indexOf($.cookie('country')) > -1
```

Also , instead of

```
 countryArray = new Array["DE", "ES", "AT", "IT", "NL"];
```

you need to write:

```
 countryArray = ["DE", "ES", "AT", "IT", "NL"];
```

**UPDATE:** For old browsers include this script in your `js`:

```
 Array.prototype.indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf || function( value, startIndex ){
     var i = startIndex || 0;
     for(; i < this.length; ++i){
         if( value === this[i] ){
             return i;
         }          
     }
     return -1;
 }
```

Comment: what abt older versions of IE?

Comment: @Baz1nga I did not know,that `indexOf` works only for new browsers.Thanks for valuable comment.I have updated my answer.

Comment: Do I need to add your old browser script somewhere specific? before / after my if statement? in the the document.ready() ?

Comment: Add it wherever you want,the only rule, it must be executed before using `indexOf`. It does not metter in `document.ready` or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

have an associative array instead.

```
var countryArray = [];

countryArray["DE"]=true;
countryArray["ES"]=true;
etc.

if( $.cookie('country') && countryArray[$.cookie('country')] )
 { alert("working"); }
```

Will work in all browsers..